# php json вывести множество элементов из бд

Tags: php, json

В моем коде выводится только один первый встречаемый элемент из бд с определенным `id_user`, а мне нужно вывести все элементы с данным `id_user` через json.

```html
$query = "Select * from Historybalans where id_user = '$id_user'";
$result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$user_text_count = $row['text_count'];
$user_text_info = $row['text_info']; 
$json['text_count'] = $user_text_count;
$json['text_info'] = $user_text_info;
```

Answer (score -1):

Решение:

```html
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $user_text_count = $row['text_count'];
    $user_text_info = $row['text_info']; 
    $json['text_count'] = $user_text_count;
    $json['text_info'] = $user_text_info;
    echo json_encode($json);
}
```